# Django: `MergeDict` is deprecated, use `dict.update()` instead

Tags: python, django, dictionary, merge

I get this message:

```
RemovedInDjango19Warning: MergeDict is deprecated, use dict.update() instead.
```

Current code:

```
return MergeDict(dict_a, dict_b)
```

This is no solution, since `dict_a` gets modified:

```
return dict_a.update(dict_b) #1
```

Moreover `dict_a` is an instance of a custom class which does not support copying (it is lazy and creates items on the fly depending on the key), so I cannot simply do:

```
new=dict()
new.update(dict_a)
new.update(dict_b)
return new
```

How do I replace `MergeDict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap). It does the same thing as `MergeDict`: keeps a list of mappings and accesses them in order.

However it's generally simpler to just actually perform the merge of the dictionaries. It probably isn't impossible to add copying support to your custom class and just update it.

Comment: How this is different from the code OP gives? The problem is that dict_a is lazy.

Comment: @guettli Use `ChainMap` then.

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you for your answer. ChainMap works great. For all those people fixed on Python2.7: On pypi there is a backport available: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chainmap/